# So how did the date go?

Tags: logical-deduction

It's Monday morning. Fernando just sat down at his desk for another hard day at work - programming stuff and answering telephone calls - "have you tried turning it off and on again?"

As he is about to login onto his machine he notices a tiny bit of yellow paper sticking out from underneath the keyboard. He moves the keyboard away to find a sticky note with the following text on it:

```
51577830494373674D773D3D
```

He is not quite sure what to make of it, but he thinks that the new intern, Ganna, left it for him. The previous night the two were out on a date. He took her to this fancy restaurant and they seemed to have a really good time together. However when they had almost finished eating, she received a call and after a brief moment she said she had an urgent matter to attend to - promptly leaving without offering any explanation.

This made him think that she didn't actually enjoy the date at all - so he didn't quite bother call her afterwards.

**Hints:**

> #1 (Obvious): Ganna is also a WINDOWS software developer. [Thanks for pointing out guys]

Comment: Aw. Charming puzzle, Zuiq!

Comment: Clearly not a very good engineer then.  The message is blantantly longer than the information she wishes to convey.

Comment: @Neil: Have you ever met a woman?

Comment: @Twinkles Ever had a sense of humor?

Comment: I think saying "Have you ever met a woman" proves he has a sense of humour. Calm down :)

Comment: I can't imagine herself improvising that hex right there on the spot, and even if she did, that would be one filled sticky note lol. But let's just assume that she did for the purpose of this puzzle :)

Comment: Taking your own intern out on a date is a bloody stupid idea.

Comment: i can't help but notice the `3D3D` at the end... http://4d3d3d3.com/

Comment: Where does it say she was his intern?  It says "the new intern", he could very well be the second newest. "...rumoresque senum severiorum omnes unius aestimemus assis!"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Three steps:

> Since there is no higher letter than F we can assume it is Hex code, if we convert it to ASCII: `QWx0ICsgMw==`

This looks like

> a base64-encoded string. If we decode that: `Alt + 3`

Which gives us the following result when used in a web browser:

> ♥

Comment: Well, that was quick :) Good job Twinkles.

Comment: Oh, the things I'd do for love...

Comment: Where does Alt+3 create a heart symbol?

Comment: @hexafraction Open google, hold down Alt, type 3, then release the Alt key. :)

Comment: @Manu this sends me to my 3rd open tab :D (not very romantic)

Comment: Generally you use the numpad for alt codes. `Alt + Numpad 3` would probably be a bit more appropriate, but it wouldn't be a puzzle without some details being implicit.

Comment: For me, on Linux (Ubuntu Trusty), neither `Alt + 3`, nor `Alt + Numpad 3` gives a heart symbol in neither Chrome nor Firefox. Many of my dates and most of the geeks I know also use Linux, so it doesn't apply to them either. So this puzzle is not universal at all.

Comment: Alt+(Numpad)3 works on Windows. So Ganna is a windows developer, which explains why she prefers long, convoluted, cryptic stuff over short and readable code.

Comment: `"look, it's not you, it's your Operating System..."`

Comment: I think that this puzzle might be better with a starting message of "4A694E344D6A59324E54733D" Edit: For the final step to my variant, you might need this: http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu Trusty, so I'm getting third tab in Firefox, third window in irssi, etc.

Comment: I think this depends on the active code page and operating system.... AHA! [Windows Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)  is the character set of the original IBM PC (personal computer), or MS-DOS in Western PCs.

Comment: Yeah, character \003 is very PC-specific.  But at least Ganna knows about base64!

Comment: Wow, I had to test all the Alt + Numpad combinations ☺